# Python, change a var by a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I have multiple `type1 = Label(image=type_none)` and get a list `['Ground', 'Rock', 'Water']` and want to change it to

`type1 = Label(image=type_Ground)`

`type2 = Label(image=type_Rock)`

etc. The `type_Rock` are already defined, and contain Data i want to Display.

So i am looking for a way to dynamically change the Variable. Something like this.

```py
for i in range(0, len(type_list)):
    type{i} = Label(image=type_{type_list[i]})
```

In the end it should update the Images of the Labels 1 through X. I am still a beginner and cant find a way to do this. I would post the full code, but it is large and messy. In case you need to know, the Image i have to define as `self.type_ground = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img/Ground.png").resize(self.type_size))`
Thanks for your time reading through my Problems :)

**Edit:** Thanks for the Answers, i initially looked at eval(), and it worked fine, but i ran into some issues and because you all said it was bad practices, i now use dicts and lists containing the Variables.

The Image can be easily created like so: `type_img = {"Scaning": ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img/Scaning.png").resize(type_size))}`,

but the `Tk.Label` objects, i needed to handle different.
First i create the Label `wtype0 = Label(master, image=type_img["None"])`, place it in Tkinter, then store it in a list `type_tklist = [self.wtype0]`

Then when i want to change the images, i can simply

```py
for i in range(0, len(weak1)):
     self.type_tklist[i].configure(image=self.type_img[weak1[i]])
     self.type_tklist[i].image = self.type_img[weak1[i]]
```

Comment: Just create a list or dict of Labels. Creating dynamic variable names is not the way to go.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`. Don't dynamically create variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: This is a common question that comes up frequently from new programmers - it's generally a bad idea, there's almost always better ways to solve a problem than self-modifying code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is possible...

This is possible, using the built-in function [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), but it is almost always a very bad idea. Regardless, if you'd want to do this, you could do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(type_list)):
    eval('type{} = something'.format(i))
```

### But there are always better options

Instead, consider using a list of types:

```
types = []
for i in range(0, len(type_list)):
    types.append(something)
```

which you can then access like `types[1]`.

If you want better "names" for the different types than just numbers, consider using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 3):

you can create string and then use eval()

ex :

```
    eval(f"type{i} = Label(image=type_{type_list[i]})")
```

Comment: Although technically correct, it's incredibly bad advice. Self modifying code is definitely not the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible using Python's [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function, but it's considered bad programming practice.

Instead of defining your images as `type_Rock`, `type_Ground`, I'd recommend creating a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) `type_images` where your key is `Rock`, `Ground`, etc.

Your loop would look like:

```
for t, img in type_images.items():
    type{i} = Label(image=img)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there are a couple of routes to choose in my mind: one using classes and the other using a dictionary. For speed, I will show the method with a dictionary with an enumeration method to get by having to fiddle too much with indices.

```
data = {}
names = ["Ground", "Rock", "Water"]

for i, type in enumerate(type_list):
   key = names[i] 
   data[key] = Label(image=type)
```

From here, you can choose the data you want to work with by simply keying the name of the type you're interested in; for instance:

```
# type1
type1 = data["Ground"]
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood.